# how to get sum of numbers in list between two other numbers

Tags: python, list

I want to get sum of numbers from list, for example, [1, 6, 3, 4, 7, 6] between 6 and 7. 
I write some code and it works, but I would like to know how to make it easier.

```
def s(numbers: list):
   six, seven, result = [], [], 0
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        if numbers[i] == 6:
            six.append(i)
        if numbers[i] == 7:
            seven.append(i)
    if len(six) == 0:
        return 0
    elif len(seven) == 0:
        for i in six:
            numbers = numbers[i + 1:]
        for i in range(len(numbers)):
            result += numbers[i]
    for i, j in zip(six, seven):
        for index in range(i + 1, j):
            if numbers[index] != 7:
                result += numbers[index]
    return result
```

Comment: You want to take the sublist between the two numbers you want to find the sum between, and sum that up. For `l = [1, 6, 3, 4, 7, 6]`, you want `sum(l[1:5])`

Comment: I'm wondering why this question is getting close votes, he has the good question with approach and seeking for better approaches

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear from your question if you want to sum the numbers between the 6th and 7th element or the values that are in the range of 6-7. If you wish to do the latter.

```
result = 0
for number in numbers:
    if 6<= number <= 7:
        result += number
```